# Xquery for Nest and concate

Tags: xquery

Here is my modified input XML:

```
 <Input>
<BIKey></BIKey>
<BusinessObjects>
      <BusinessObject>
        <BusinessIdentifiers>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
            <BValue>CDC</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuType</BKey>
            <BValue>123</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
            <BValue>857895</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
        </BusinessIdentifiers>
        <BusinessAttributes>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>Version</BKey>
            <BValue>1</BValue> 
          </BusinessAttribute>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>date</BKey>
            <BValue>2018-06-28</BValue>
          </BusinessAttribute>
        </BusinessAttributes>
      </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
        <BusinessIdentifiers>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
            <BValue>CDC</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuType</BKey>
            <BValue>123</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
            <BValue>34567</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
        </BusinessIdentifiers>
        <BusinessAttributes>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>Version</BKey>
            <BValue>1</BValue> 
          </BusinessAttribute>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>date</BKey>
            <BValue>2018-06-28</BValue>
          </BusinessAttribute>
        </BusinessAttributes>
      </BusinessObject>      
    </BusinessObjects>
    </Input>
```

I would like to get the following output `CDC|123|857895:CDC|123|34567` assigned to `<BIKey>`.

I have tried this Xquery:

```
<Input>    
    <BIKey>{ string-join(data($Input/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue),'|') }</BIKey>
</Input>
```

But I got this output `CDC|123|857895|CDC|123|34567`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the wrong function, use `string-join(sequence, '|')`, not `concat` e.g.

```
<Input>    
    <BIKey>{ string-join(Input/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|') }</BIKey>
</Input>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5e

Comment: Hi Martin, can you help me with the modified input XML

Comment: @sivakumarkala, don't change your requirements once you have received an answer that solved the original problem. Ask a new question if necessary.

Comment: Thanks i will ask in next question.